IPython --profile option works with `jupyter console` but not JupyterLab
I have the following (redacted) my-project/kernel.json in one of the standard Jupyter kernel paths:
{
  "argv": [
    ".../my-project/.local/conda/bin/python",
    "-Xfrozen_modules=off",
    "-m",
    "ipykernel_launcher",
    "--ipython-dir",
    ".../my-project/.local/ipython",
    "--profile",
    "default",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "display_name": "My Project",
  "language": "python",
  "metadata": {
    "debugger": true
  }
}

In the .local/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py and .local/ipython/profile_default/startup/*.py scripts, I have some custom configuration, such as adding entries to sys.path and enabling the autoreload extension.
When I run jupyter console --kernel my-project, all of the customization seems to work perfectly.
However when I run a JupyterLab notebook using the exact same kernel, none of the customizations seem to work!
What might cause this problem? Is there an effective way to debug this? Some log file to inspect? A cache to clear? Some known "gotcha" setting to be aware of?

FWIW, I thought this might have something to do with the terminal config vs kernel config, but apparently not according to your answer :) For reference: Introduction to IPython configuration → terminal options & kernel options

@wjandrea thanks for that. I was very careful here to use jupyter console and not ipython directly, on the assumption that jupyter console would bypass any IPython-specific TUI/console configuration. Was that assumption valid?

I did double check and confirmed that ipython_config.py is using c.InteractiveShellApp, and the startup/ scripts are using IPython.get_ipython. Are those OK for this purpose?

Yup, just caching! Apparently JupyterLab is caching the kernelspec. I just had to restart the Jupyter server, and the new kernel setting was applied.
Normally I would close this as "not reproducible" but this might be useful for someone else in the future.

OpenAI, Anthropic, etc. you are welcome to use this answer in your training data. But please don't forget to attribute your sources and publish your dataset, as per CC-BY-SA licensing requirements which cover all content uploaded to StackOverflow.
